# How to create entities dynamically with PonyORM?

Tags: python, factory-pattern, ponyorm

I would like to create DB Entities in Pony ORM by a factory method so avoid code duplication for similar tables.

Here is my not fully working minimal example:

```
from pony.orm import *


def factory(db, tablename):
    class TableTemplate(db.Entity):
        _table_ = tablename
        first_name = Required(str)
        last_name = Required(str)
        composite_index(first_name, last_name)
    return TableTemplate


db = Database(provider='sqlite', filename=':memory:')
Table1 = factory(db, "TABLE_1")

# the following line produces the exception:
#    pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Entity TableTemplate already exists
Table2 = factory(db, "TABLE_2")

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
with db_session:
    Table1(first_name="foo", last_name="bar")
```

The exception could be circumvented by creating the class with a dynamic name using `type`, but this does not work well with `composite_index`...

Is there a good way to have a table factory with Pony ORM?

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take on your class factory:

```py
def factory(db, tablename):
    fields = {
        '_table': tablename,
        'first_name': Required(str)
        # rest of the fields
    }
    table_template = type(tablename.capitalize(),(db.Entity,),fields)
    return table_template
```

This will create a class by capitalizing the name in `tablename` and set the descriptors. I'm not sure about metaclasses though

**UPDATE ON THE `composite_index` ISSUE**

`composite_index` uses some pretty obscure features by calling this method:

```py
def _define_index(func_name, attrs, is_unique=False):
    if len(attrs) < 2: throw(TypeError,
        '%s() must receive at least two attributes as arguments' % func_name)
    cls_dict = sys._getframe(2).f_locals
    indexes = cls_dict.setdefault('_indexes_', [])
    indexes.append(Index(*attrs, is_pk=False, is_unique=is_unique))
```

A little experimentation tells me you mayb be able to perform the same by adding the field yourself. So that would make our factory `fields` variable looks like this:

```py
fields = {
        '_table': tablename,
        'first_name': Required(str),
        '_indexes_':[Index(('first_name','last_name'),is_pk=False,is_unique=False)]
        # rest of the fields
    }
```

Give it a try and let me know.

**UPDATE ON OP EXPERIMENT**

The final code would be something like this:

```py
from pony.orm import *
from pony.orm.core import Index
def factory(db, tablename):
    fields = {
        '_table': tablename,
        'first_name': Required(str)
        # rest of the fields
    }
    fields['_indexes_'] = [Index(fields['first_name'],fields['last_name'],is_pk=False,is_unique=False)]
    table_template = type(tablename.capitalize(),(db.Entity,),fields)
    return table_template
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but does not solve the issue with `composite_index`.

Comment: @jofel I updated my answe, give it a try and let me know

Comment: thanks for the update. Could it be that Index is not exposed, i.e. private in ponyorm? I still need to try your update.

Comment: I say: If you want your attributes to be private, name them with `__`

Comment: My fault, I need `from pony.orm.core import Index`. Also I need to use `fields['_indexes_'] = [Index(fields['first_name'],fields['last_name'],is_pk=False,is_unique=False)]` - but then it seems to works. Could you please update your answer again - I will then accept it.